# Googlemap API with PHP, Geocode doesn't work anymore

Tags: api, google-maps, timeout, geocoding

I use googlemap api to geocode adresse on my test server (nobody can access to this server).
Everything worked perfectly for many month. It's a test server,so I don not reach the quota. But since yesterday, Google doesn't answer anything (fopen with PHP). I have no error message ... just timeout...nothing else.

Any idea ? (blacklist ? network problem ?)

For example, this code doesn't work now (timeout) :

```
$sTest = file_get_contents( "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json" );
echo $sTest;
```

Another simple test with same result... without php (SSH) :

```
wget http://www.google.com -q --delete-after
```

ping is OK.

Thanks

Comment: What does you code look like? Which Geocoding API are you using?

Comment: file_get_contents() on http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json

Comment: Please update your question with your code and the details requested.